# Installed LibreOffice via apt, will AppCenter update it?

Tags: appcenter, release-odin, libreoffice

how it's going on?

I installed LibreOffice via synaptic and apt since I had problems with saving documents in the Flathub version. That being said, AppCenter doesn't show my new Libre Office install, so, will App Center handle its updates?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering the same, see here: https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/pcl1u0/apps_installed_using_deb_files_and_snap/.